# PHP CodeIgniter 4 Framework - Getting Error 419 Page Expired

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Hi I am using PHP CodeIgniter 4 framework in my application. It's working fine but if my application is open and there is no activity on the page after 20-30 mins if I try to access the page it gives me an error ***419 Page Expired!
Sorry, the page has expired, return to previous page and refresh to continue.***
I want application to redirect to login page instead of show this error. How can I fix please?

Comment: which version of codeigniter are you using? what have you tried so far?

Comment: Version 4.1, I haven't try anything yet as no clue so far.

Comment: Show us some of your *custom* app configurations. Otherwise, we have so little information to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

it is happen in codigniter 4 because the $config['csrf_protection'] is true in config/config.php file.
to remove this error you have to set $config['csrf_exclude_uris']=array('your api path/controller name/your method');

Comment: The `$config` variable is used in CodeIgniter3. Though the OP is using CodeIgniter4.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).